# Add a property to a json string with jackson json

Tags: java, javascript, json, jackson

I am storing a json string into a text field in mysql.
After the insertion, i want to update my json string and add the mysql line id into it with jackson json.

I have a java String which is in Json format

```
{
  "thing":"val"
}
```

I'm looking to add another K/V without writing lines of codes.

to finally have this :

```
{
  "thing":"val"
  "mysqlId":10
}
```

I can convert my String to a JsonNode :

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
JsonNode json = mapper.readTree( jsonStr);
```

Looking to do something like this

```
json.put("mysqlId",10);
json.toString();
```

then update in my text field with new json string in mysql

I can't make it.
I don't want use many class is there a simple way to do so with jackson?

Comment: Sounds like an odd requirement. Can you give an example of what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm updating the post

Comment: Try updating your question instead with the example code.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Try casting your `JsonNode` to an `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode` and then calling <s>put</s> `set` (or `replace`) on it.

Comment: *put* method in ObjectNode is deprecated in v2.4. You need to use *set* or *replace*.

Comment: is there a way to leverage Jackson to just change the *name* of a property in a JSON string? I.e. suppose I want to change `'id' : 42` to `'my_id' : 42` - without having to know the value 42 and re-creating the property?