# Json From RESTFul

Tags: java, json, spring, rest

I'm trying to create Spring Restful Service which should return :

{"counts": [{"SearchText1": 11}, {"SearchText2": 16}, {"SearchText3": 8}]}

Where "SearchText1" is the text to be search for in a document and 11 is the number of recurrence.

I have been trying to model this Json as java classes to return so it can be serialized to Json but no luck yet!

```
 public class CountResultWrapper {

     List<CountResult> counts = new  ArrayList<CountResult>();

    public List<CountResult> getCounts() {
        return counts;
    }

    public void setCounts(List<CountResult> counts) {
        this.counts = counts;
    }

    }

public class CountResult {

    String searchText;
    Integer count;


    public CountResult(String searchText,Integer count)
    {
        this.searchText = searchText;
        this.count = count;
    }

    public String getSearchText() {
        return searchText;
    }
    public void setSearchText(String searchText) {
        this.searchText = searchText;
    }
    public Integer getCount() {
        return count;
    }
    public void setCount(Integer count) {
        this.count = count;
    }

}
```

but I get this:

```
{"counts":[{"searchText":"searchText1","count":11},{"searchText":"searchText2","count":8},{"searchText":"searchText3","count":7}]}
```

can some one help me please?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16561989/add-a-property-to-a-json-string-with-jackson-json

Comment: Thanks I modified the code and  added my code

Comment: If you want to *create* your own JSON then hand-craft it, or change your classes to suit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I solved it:

```
    List<HashMap<String, Integer>> countsList = new ArrayList<>();
    searchTexts.forEach(searchText ->{
         countsList.add(new HashMap<String, Integer>()
         {{put(searchText,countMap.get(searchText.toUpperCase()) == null ? 0 : countMap.get(searchText.toUpperCase()));}});
    });
    Map<String, List<HashMap<String, Integer>>> response = new HashMap<>();
    response.put("counts", countsList);
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the field name is dynamic, It cannot be directly achieved using a model class - as you cannot have new fields for every searchtext record.

However, it can be achieved using below - it may be costly for large volume, but it returns you the expected output

```
        List<HashMap<String, Integer>> counts = new ArrayList<>();
        counts.add(new HashMap<String, Integer>() {{put("SearchText1",11);}});
        counts.add(new HashMap<String, Integer>() {{put("SearchText2",11);}});

        JSONObject output = new JSONObject();
        output.put("counts",counts);
        System.out.println(output.toString());
```

Output :

> ```
> {
>   "counts": [{
>       "SearchText1": 11
>   }, {
>       "SearchText2": 16
>   }, {
>       "SearchText3": 8
>   }]
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You can add this class and use. that response provide json output for response. but you didn't want http response then the return type can change to JSONObject output.

```
 import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.Map;
    import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;

public class JesonCreater {


public ResponseEntity<?> responseProvider(CountResultWrapper wrapper){
    Map<String,List<HashMap<String, Integer>>> responseMap=new HashMap<>();
    List<CountResult> counts=wrapper.getCounts();
    List<HashMap<String, Integer>> countListMap = new ArrayList<>();
    for (CountResult count : counts) {
        HashMap<String, Integer> countMap=new HashMap<>();
        countMap.put(count.getSearchText(), count.getCount());
        countListMap.add(countMap);         
    }
    responseMap.put("count", countListMap);
    return ResponseEntity.ok(responseMap);
}
}
```

the answer come like this

```
{

"count": [
    {
      "searchText2": 4
    },
    {
      "searchText1": 11
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I have to tell you that you can't get the result you want in this way. The console output is properly right for your case. When converting `ConutResult` to json object, the field name will be put into the `key` and field value into the `value`. like:

```
{"searchText":"xxx", "count":xxx}
```

If you really want to do this, you may need 3 classes:

```
class CountResult1{
    private int searchText1;
}

class CountResult2{
    private int searchText2;
}

class CountResult3{
    private int searchText3;
}
```

Then the 3 classes can be converted to:

```
{"searchText1":xxx}, {"searchText2":xxx}, {"searchText3":xxx}
```