# Insert property into JSON string without parsing

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a JSON string and I want to inject one field into it, preferably without having to parse the JSON. What are some good ways of doing this? The main priority is performance.

Possible ways of doing this that I can think of:

1. Check that the first non-blank character is `{`, insert `"myField":"myValue",` directly after it in the string. Problematic if the JSON already contains `"myField"` or if the data has no properties.
2. Parse the JSON tree and insert the value normally. Easy to check for an existing 
   `myField` property, but a slower choice.

Is there some way I haven't thought of? Possibly a Jackson specific solution?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add a property to a json string with jackson json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16561989/add-a-property-to-a-json-string-with-jackson-json)

Comment: The time difference between 1 and 2 is so minor that it's almost non-existent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Manipulating a JSON document with Jackson shouldn't impact much on performance. Simply parse the JSON document using the Jackson tree model:

```java
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
JsonNode tree = mapper.readTree(json);
```

Perform your manipulations and then write the tree back to JSON.

---

> The main priority is performance.

According to Donald Knuth, [*premature optimization is the root of all evil*](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/80092/122966). Which means that in the absence of *measured* performance issues you shouldn't optimize because you *think* you will get a performance gain.

Some obvious optimizations can be performed but anything that isn't a trivially clear optimization should be avoided until it can be measured.